# Is there a where like relation function when using pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x

I have the following data:

A collection named categories that contains documents like so:

```
{
    "cat":"Films Anglais",
    "path":"W:\\videos"
}
```

Categories are unique (because I use upsert) or let's admit it is anyway.

A collection named rules that contains documents like so:

```
{
    "title":"braveheart",
    "regex":"^.*braveheart.*$",
    "cat":"Films Anglais"
}
```

I am iterating on all the rules. So I can access the cat from rules as rule['cat'].
What I need is the path from categories.

I know that I can do:

```
dest = ""
for category in categories.find():
    if category['cat'] == rule['cat']:
        dest = category['path']
        break
```

1) I would prefer the process to be database side. Like categories.find_one().distinct('path').where(cat=rule['cat'])? Invalide I know.

2) Is there a way to define a sort of relation so that I do not need to duplicate the cat field?

Lastly, I have read about the difference between relationnal and non relationnal systems but in this case the choice is sealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1), you don't want to use server-side javascript here, or ever, really. It's slow and blocks lots of other operations. Don't use server-side javascript to try and fake joins in MongoDB.

For 2), duplicating the `path` info into the `rules` documents seems like the best solution. How often will a `path` change? The cost to embedding `path` is the duplication and the need for a more expensive set of updates if a `path` changes, as compared to your current setup. Seems worth it to me, in the absence of further information about your use case.

Comment: The path was initialy in the rule. I guess I moved it out to avoid duplicates. But your point about the path changing is valid in my use case (which is moving some files in our NAS).